# Add a value in Textbox and label in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've been trying to add a value in textbox and a label. the value inside label is automatically generated during page load..it can be negative, positive or zero (decimal too). When I'm trying to add it with the textbox value I get the following error. Below is the error and code.

Input string was not in a correct format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("update dues set amount = @due where person='rahul'", con);
            cmd6.Parameters.Add("@due", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd6.Parameters["@due"].Value = int.Parse(txt_rahul.Text + lbl_rahul.Text);
            cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This means that the content of txt_rahul.Text or lbl_rahul.Text is not a number. int.Parse cannot convert it to a number.

Comment: The data type of your parameter in DB does not match the value that you are inserting to DB OR your auto generated value does not match your field data type. try this
int.Parse(txt_rahul.Text) + int.Parse(lbl_rahul.Text)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("update dues set amount = @due where person='rahul'", con);
            cmd6.Parameters.Add("@due", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd6.Parameters["@due"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(txt_rahul.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(lbl_rahul.Text);
            cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Well what values are you putting in both boxes, are you integers? Are they decimals? Are they strings?

Comment: I've put integer in textbox and decimal in label

Comment: Thanks. It is working. What if I want to store a decimal value in sql table. I've changed the SQL datatype to decimal.

Comment: use `SqlDbType.Decimal`. i am not sure. you can check the DbTypes in google

Answer (score 0):

`txt_rahul.Text + lbl_rahul.Text` would concatenate the `string`'s together, it wouldn't add them up.

You would need to parse each one into an integer first. As in:

```
int something = int.Parse(txt_rahul.Text);
int somethingElse = int.Parse(lbl_rahul.Text);
cmd6.Parameters["@due"].Value = something + somethingElse;
```

Comment: It works fine for integers but gives an error when value in label is a decimal like -162.8
Input string was not in a correct format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Well your database column is an int. You are not supplying an int. What do you expect to happen with that? If you are supply decimal's too, change the database column.